# Setting auto-resize for GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on an application in C# WPF.

I'm using a `ListView` with many `GridViewColumn`. That ListView is binding a custom class containing pictures (named Shot, in a list named Shots). When a column is empty (field of Shot is empty for all Shots) it doesn't not display. If a contain is added the column is visible and auto sized by binding IsVisible.

My Shots list is an `ObservableCollection<Shot>`

My code to refresh size is (on MainWindows.xaml.cs):

```
private void Context_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    String property = e.PropertyName;
    if (property == "Shots")
    {
        // shotsGridView is the GridView element
        foreach (GridViewColumn c in shotsGridView.Columns)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    if (GridViewColumnVisibilityManager.GetIsVisible(c))
                        c.SetValue(GridViewColumn.WidthProperty, double.NaN);
                    else
                        c.SetValue(GridViewColumn.WidthProperty, 0);
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The refresh is correctly called, only the non-empty columns are visible. The problem is that the resize is done with header size, the content is not full displayed. See columns Name & Status on example below.

[image: Example of display]

Comment: Are you using a listView or DataGrid ?

Comment: As I said "I'm using a ListView with many GridViewColumn."